# Clear a timer before timeout in javascript when the webpage is not minimized or new tab is opened

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a recursive type function onload in JavaScript that runs like this:
I have given  the timeout for the pop up as 5 seconds which is working fine.
But I want to clear the timer and close the pop up when the user is moved to a new tab so I have used "document.hidden"  property in JavaScript
But when I run the script and move to a new tab  or minimize the window  in the browser  the the timer is still not cleared and the timeout continues foe 5 seconds
Is there anything I am missing . Please advice

```
function callMe()
  {
   var delay ;
 $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation Window1",
        resizable: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        open: function (event, ui) {
               delay = setTimeout(function () {$("#dialog").dialog("close"); setTimeout(callMe,1000); }, 5000);
                  if(document.hidden) 
                    {
                    clearTimeout (delay);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    setTimeout(callMe,1000)
                    }
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
                clearTimeout (delay);
                setTimeout(callMe,1000)
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel
                clearTimeout (delay);
                setTimeout(callMe,1000)
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using window.blur and window.focus . The code is as follows :

```
 var delay ;
 function callMe()
  {


 $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation Window1",
        resizable: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        open: function (event, ui) {
               delay = setTimeout(function () {$("#dialog").dialog("close"); setTimeout(callMe,1000); }, 2000);

        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Ok
                clearTimeout (delay);
                setTimeout(callMe,1000);
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close"); //closing on Cancel
                clearTimeout (delay);
                setTimeout(callMe,1000);
            }
        }
    });

  }



  $(window).blur(function(e) {
    clearTimeout (delay);
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});


$(window).focus(function(e) {
    setTimeout(callMe,1000);
});
```